# How do i fix a white screen after replacing digitizer on Nexus 7?

Tags: screen, power-on

I replaced the screen and digitizer on my nexus 7. Now when I power up the nexus 7, it is only a white screen that flickers. I checked all wires and they are fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's too little info here. Without knowing how your device was behaving beforehand we can only assume that you did mess up the connection or broke something.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that both your screen and device are functioning, and the problem does not lie directly with either device but the connection between them?

Start diagnosing your problem by finding out whether the screen works correctly (with another device), or the device works on it's own and it's not a problem with the motherboard (another screen)?

Also try contacting the company that you bought the screen from for troubleshooting instructions and double-check you've setup the screen with your device correctly.